# Deploy my symfony project and receive 502 error

Tags: symfony, nginx

So, i want to publish my simple project in symfony to web. For that i have small dedicated server with LEMP. I configured nginx.conf according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx, but i receive 502 error.
This is my nginx.conf

```
    #user html;
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server{
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      return 301 https://www.mydoamin.pl$request_uri;
    }


    server {
          listen 443 ssl;
          server_name  mydomain.pl www.mydomain.pl;

        error_page      404 /404.php;

      ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.pl/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.pl/privkey.pem;

          root  /usr/share/nginx/html/public; 

   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

      location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
      }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }



    error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_access.log;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? ;P

Comment: php7.2-fpm servoce is running?

Comment: Yes, it's running.

Comment: Can you post fpm configuration? There is a line like this  `listen = /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock` ?

Comment: In php/php-fpm.conf i don't have this line also i don't have any listen line.

Comment: OK, i fixed that. I addes listen 127.0.0.1:9000 to nginx.conf file and www.conf. Thanks. I search listen line in php-fpm.conf, but it's in www.conf.

Comment: If you want the `php-fpm` to listen on the port and not use a unix socket you need to configure nginx to pass the request to that url. Adjust the `fastcgi_pass` value of your nginx configuration. `www.conf` is fine as long as you only have one worker configuration for your `php-fpm`.